# Getting same object from two views

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I have tree models 'cinema', 'cinemaHall' and 'seo', where 'cinema' has relationship @OneToMany to 'cinemaHall'. Also, 'cinema' and 'cinemaHall' models have relationship @OneToOne to 'seo'. The problem is in model seo. After creating 'cinema' and 'cinemaHall' I'm getting, the same 'seo' from Thymeleaf, which is related to 'cinema'. But I need to received 'seo' (for example, with id = 2) for 'cinemaHall'. Please, find the screenshot for understanding.

## CinemaController.java:

```
...
@PutMapping("update/{cinemaId}")
    public String updateCinema(@PathVariable("cinemaId") Long cinemaId,
                               @ModelAttribute("cinema") Cinema cinema,
                               @ModelAttribute("seo") SEO seo){
        cinema.setSeo(seo);
        cinemaService.updateCinema(cinema);
        return "redirect:/admin/cinemas";
    }
...
 @PutMapping("edit/{cinemaId}/halls/update/{hallId}")
    public String updateCinemaHall(@PathVariable("cinemaId") Long cinemaId,
                                   @PathVariable("hallId") Long hallId,
                                   @ModelAttribute("cinemaHall") CinemaHall cinemaHall,
                                   @ModelAttribute("seo") SEO seo){
        cinemaHall.setSeo(seo);
        cinemaHallService.updateCinemaHall(cinemaHall);
        return "redirect:/admin/cinemas/edit/" + cinemaId;
    }
...
```

## Cinema.java

```
...
@OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="cinema_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private List<CinemaHall> cinemaHallList = new ArrayList<>();
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "seo_id")
    private SEO seo;
...
```

## CinemaHall.java

```
...
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "seo_id")
    private SEO seo;
...
```

## SEO.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "seo")
public class SEO extends MappedEntity {

    @Column
    private String url;
    @Column
    private String title;
    @Column
    private String keywords;
    @Column(name = "seo_description")
    private String seoDescription;

}
```

After creating, for example, cinema(id=1) and seo(id=1) I'm trying to create cinemaHall(id=1) while seo(id=2) was successfully created too, but after applying action for saving cinemaHall I'm receiving seo with id=1 and fields like it has from id=2.
[Look at seo which has id=1, but should be id=2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBSPV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the one to many mapping between cinema and cinemaHall if u have one-to-one  mapping between cinema and seo AND cinemaHall and seo.

just use one to one mapping and this should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your given relationship is not working possibility.because A to B relationship is fine and A to C Or B to C any One relationship only possible both are not possible.

A and B Both need relationship to C then no need of A to B relationship.If B have relation with C then A can have access to to C Object from respective B object.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).